# Divisibility of Integers and TD

Tags: divisibility

Is it true that if $3|x$ and $3|y$ and $3|z$ then $3|(x+y+z)?$
If yes how do I prove it?
If not how do I work through a problem like this?

Comment: What does TD mean?

Comment: @coffeemath Test for Divisibility maybe?

Comment: @JohhnySmith Beware of abbreviations like TD unless you are really sure they are in general use. I have been in math for decades and have no idea what it means. The fact that a book uses it is far from conclusive evidence that it is widely used.

Answer (score 2):

$3a=x,\ 3b=y,\ 3c=z,$ now factor out $3$ and put $d=a+b+c.$ Then $3d=x+y+z$ so...